# SQL Server on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, sql-server-vnext

I'm trying to install SQL Server vNext on Linux Mint.
when i run setup, I get the following error. any help would be highly appreciated.

```
Failed to issue method call: No such interface 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' 
on object at path /org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/mssql_2dserver_2eservice
```

Comment: solved after upgrading Mint from 17.1 to 18

Answer (score -1):

**Installing SQL Server on Linux Ubuntu or Linux mint**

You should install Microsoft odbc driver on your Linux, when you want to remote to a SQL server on any other operation system or work with sqlcmd (that it's support SQL server instructions).

First of all, you need to be super user:

```
sudo su
```

Then, add Microsoft packages repository to your own Linux.

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
```

Download appropriate package for the OS version
Choose only ONE of the following, corresponding to your OS version

```
lsb_release -a
```

Ubuntu 16.04

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
```

Ubuntu 18.04

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/18.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
```

Ubuntu 19.10, 20.04

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/19.10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
```

After that, exit from super user login.

```
exit
```

Update your aptitude package list cache.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install msodbcsql package. This is your Microsoft odbc driver.

```
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev
```

If you want to remotely connect to a SQL server on any other operating system (like windows), you can use only odbc driver. But, if you want to install sql server on your own Linux and using it, you should type this following commands:

```
# optional: for bcp and sqlcmd
sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install mssql-tools
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

> ref:
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
>
> Removing:
>   https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174176