# SQL Server on Linux : Data source name not found

Tags: sql-server, linux

I followed the [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu) to install Sql server natively on my machine which runs linux mint sonya based off ubuntu xenial.

Ive had no trouble installing the service:

```
$ systemctl status mssql-server
● mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-09-27 17:13:12 PDT; 18s ago
     Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 4139 (sqlservr)
    Tasks: 158
   Memory: 877.1M
      CPU: 4.543s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─4139 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
           └─4150 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

When trying to connect the the DB, i get this error:

```
$ sqlcmd -S localhost
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Data source name not found, and no default driver specified.
```

Comment: Please check your installation steps by [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47120746/8584198)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out after all that I did not install the unixodbc-dev package. The error message kind of threw me off.